# Debug GridView Update failure c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have read and read again the links on GridView updating. I am not new to this but I cannot make the GridView Update work. Can you have a look?

```
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_Drivers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ThinairConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [User_Id], [User_Active], [User_Reference], [User_Name], [User_Login], [User_Password] FROM [Users] WHERE ([User_Acct_Number] = @User_Acct_Number) ORDER BY [User_Name]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Users] SET [User_Active] = @User_Active, [User_Reference] = @User_Reference, [User_Name] = @User_Name, [User_Login] = @User_Login, [User_Password] = @User_Password WHERE ([User_Id] = @User_Id)" OnUpdating="sds_Drivers_Updating">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="User_Acct_Number" SessionField="Acct_Number" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="User_Active" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="User_Reference" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="User_Name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="User_Login" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="User_Password" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="User_Id" Type="Int32" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:GridView ID="gv_Drivers" runat="server"
                    Width="100%"
                    AllowSorting="True"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataKeyNames="User_Id"
                    ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False"
                    DataSourceID="sds_Drivers"
                    CellSpacing="2"
                    CellPadding="2"
                    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black"
                    HeaderStyle-Wrap="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField EditText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" ValidationGroup="Group3" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Id" HeaderText="User Id" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="User_Id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Active" HeaderText="1 = Active / 0 = Inactive" SortExpression="User_Active" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Reference" HeaderText="Your Reference" SortExpression="User_Reference" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Name" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="User_Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Login" HeaderText="User Login" SortExpression="User_Login" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="User_Password" HeaderText="User Password" SortExpression="User_Password" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        No Drivers Loaded
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:GridView>
```

What I tried for debugging in code behind:

```
        protected void sds_Drivers_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter p in e.Command.Parameters)
        {
            Response.Write(p.ParameterName + ": " + p.Value + "<br />");
        }
    }
```

The good news is I have values. The bad news is that these are not the new values in the edit fields.

What did I miss?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's very bad from a design perspective to have your data access in your ASPX page. Your data access should be performed in a separate layer. Use your code behind to tie them together.

Comment: Most of my projects are code behind. However for this down and dirty I used the ASP.net tools. I would like to see more on this being very bad from a design perspective utilizing the tools included in .net.

Comment: Have you not heard of Separation of Concerns? Keeping your data retrieval and updating separate from your business and view logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 protected void sds_Drivers_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter p in e.Command.Parameters)
            {
                Response.Write(p.ParameterName + ": " + p.NewValues + "<br />");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use p.NewValues instead of p.Values.